# How to solve open_basedir restriction in effect erro

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a pdf using `fpdf` but when I am running this on the localhost then I am getting no problem

but when I am running on worpdress server then I am getting following error :

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/a1302477/public_html/wp-content/plugins/roque/fpdf/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u541784927:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.3/pear) in /home/u541784927/public_html/wp-content/plugins/roque/fpdf/font/unifont/ttfonts.php on line 496

Warning: fopen(/home/a1302477/public_html/wp-content/plugins/roque/fpdf/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/u541784927/public_html/wp-content/plugins/roque/fpdf/font/unifont/ttfonts.php on line 496
Can't open file /home/a1302477/public_html/wp-content/plugins/roque/fpdf/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
```

How can I solve this problem, please help

To create pdf I am using code

```
require('fpdf/tfpdf.php');

    echo $quix = $_POST['quizzz'];

    $pdf = new tFPDF();

    $questions = $_POST['question'];

    $count = count($questions);

    $quests = "";

    $pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);

    $pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

    $pdf->SetFont('times','',12);

    $pdf->SetTextColor(50,60,100);



    $pdf->AddPage('P');

    //$pdf->SetDisplayMode(real,'default');



    $pdf->SetFontSize(12);



    for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)

    {

        $qus_id = $questions[$i-1];

        $get_q = "select * from `SelleXam_question` where `id`='$qus_id'";

        $get_q =  $wpdb->get_results($get_q);

        $questf = "Quest $i : ".$get_q[0]->question;

                $pdf->Cell(0, 10, iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2', $questf)."\n");                              if($get_q[0]->image !=='')      {           $pdf->Ln();         $path = plugins_url();          $imagenurl = $path.'/roque/uploads/'.$get_q[0]->image;                      $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $pdf->Image($imagenurl,$pdf->GetX()+60, $pdf->GetY() + 5,50,50), 0, 0, 'L','');       }

        $questf = "Option 1 : ".$get_q[0]->op1;

        $pdf->Ln();

        $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $questf."\n");

        $questf = "Option 2 : ".$get_q[0]->op2;

        $pdf->Ln();

        $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $questf."\n");

        $questf = "Option 3 : ".$get_q[0]->op3;

        $pdf->Ln();

        $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $questf."\n");

        $questf = "Option 4 : ".$get_q[0]->op4;

        $pdf->Ln();

        $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $questf."\n");

        $pdf->Ln();

        $pdf->Ln();
```

Comment: it looks like, you are mixing your paths from different servers. please show your code at the line 496 (or where you pass the path to your fpdf class)

Comment: I have not made any hard coded path then how can I mix them:

Comment: I have not made any hard coded path then how can I mix them:

Comment: how does it come that the file is in `/home/u541784927` and requests another one in `/home/a1302477`?